# How do I create Basic Authentication in Web Api?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following  .cs  in order to create some basic authentication in my api. This works fine,but it appears only one time, when i run it for the first time.How do I make it appear again (in every run)?

```
namespace CMob
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            var authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            var decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
            var usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
            var userName = usernamePasswordArray[0];
            var password = usernamePasswordArray[1];


            var isValid = userName == "chrysa" && password == "1234";

            if (isValid)
            {
                var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), null);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                return;
            }
        }

        HandleUnathorized(actionContext);
    }

    private static void HandleUnathorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Scheme='Data' location = 'http://localhost:");
    }
}
}¨
```

My controller

```
 public class DController : ApiController
    {
        [BasicAuthentication]
        [Route("api/D")]
        public IEnumerable<D> Get()
        {
            using (CM_DataEntities entities = new CM_DataEntities())
            {
                return entities.Ds.ToList();
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"To unauthenticated requests, the server should return a response whose header contains a HTTP 401 Unauthorized status[4] and a WWW-Authenticate field.[5]"

You should refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication.
I am quite sure you can find the answer you're looking for over there.

Basically, The browser provides authentication, and you have absolutely no control over it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the attribute in WebApiConfig.cs :

```
config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
```

And you have to decorate your Controllers and or Actions :

```
public class MyController : ApiController  
{  
  [BasicAuthentication]  
  public string Get()  
  {  
     return "Hello";  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what behavior you want to define.
If you wish to use your authentication filter for your whole API, you can add it to the global filter list this way (in WebApiConfig.cs) :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
}
```

If you desire to restrict all methods of a controller, decorate it this way :

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public class RestrictedController : ApiController
{
   //Your controller definition
}
```

Of course you can use it on a single method, this way :

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public JsonResult GetJsonDataAsAuthenticatedUser()
{
    //your method definition
}
```

You can specify a method which require no authentication with AllowAnonymous decoration :

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public class RestrictedController : ApiController
{
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public IActionResult Authenticate()
   {
      //Your authentication entry point
   }       
}
```

You can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)